# How to parse a multi-level json structure in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

The JSON from server looks like this:

A dictionary where the value is another dictionary.

```
{
    "S1": {
        "vpn_status": 2,
        "vpn_name": "vpn1"
    },
    "S2": {
        "vpn_status": 1,
        "vpn_name": "vpn2"
    }
}
```

I have created the following struct to parse it.

```
public struct ServerStatusResult {

    public let vpnName: String
    public let status: Int

    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let vpnName = json["vpn_name"] as? String,
            let status = json["vpn_status"] as? Int
            else {
                return nil
        }
        self.vpnName = vpnName
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

And the function to call the server is:

```
typealias serverStatusCompletedClosure = (_ status: Bool, _ result: Dictionary<String,ServerStatusResult>?, _ error: ServiceError?)->Void

func serverStatus(email: String, password: String, complete: @escaping serverStatusCompletedClosure) {
        let url = URL(string: "...")!
        try? self.httpClient.get(url: url,
                                token: "...",
                                email: email,
                                password: password)
        { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                complete(false, nil, ServiceError.invalidSession)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
                case 200:
                    var result: [String:ServerStatusResult]? = nil
                    result = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, ServerStatusResult>
                    complete(true, result, nil)
```

This is where my json transformation fails.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fff8eaee9b0) to
>   'app.ServerStatusResult' (0x10021dec0).

What am I missing please?

Comment: Why not use `Decodable` and decode a dictionary `[String: ServerStatusResult]`? `

Comment: Sure, can you show me how? :-)

Comment: Try using JSONDecoder instead of JSONSerialization

Comment: Are you sure the response? Because the response which you shared is not has a type like `[String: ServerStatusResult]` if it is you missed something because I couldn't see any `[` `]` between `String` to `ServerStatusResult` fields

Comment: is there a fix number of dict inside the main dictionary or it can be any?

Comment: This will help: https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using Decodable and using a dictionary

First make your struct conform to `Decodable`

```
public struct ServerStatusResult: Decodable {
    public let vpnName: String
    public let status: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vpnName = "vpn_name"
        case status = "vpn_status"
    }
}
```

and then the decoding is easy

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: ServerStatusResult].self, from: data)
    print(result) //or in you case complete(true, result, nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an array of dictionary `[[String: Any]]`

Create a struct for a dictionary and if a dictionary has another dictionary inside it then create another struct for the inner Dictionary and create an object in the outer struct for innner dictionary json.

You can use `codeable` to parse your json easily, by inheriting your struct with codeable